# Need to Hide <a> Tag that is generated automatically from other source

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, xslt, rss

I need to put RSS viewer web part that shows Stock Quotes for JPMorgan Chase.

RSS feed that I found for that is : `http://www.quoterss.com/quote.php?symbol=JPM&format=0&uid=1280868448` but his feed also retrives unnecessary links such as FaceBook cheat codes, Iphone cheat codes ... I want to hide those unnecessary links for the cheat codes.

XSLT for RSS viewer web part having above mentioned feed is provided below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl ddwrt msxsl rssaggwrt" 
               xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"
               xmlns:rssaggwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v3/rssagg/runtime"
               xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
               xmlns:rssFeed="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:RSSAggregatorWebPart"
               xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
               xmlns:rss1="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
               xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"
               xmlns:atom2="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">

    <xsl:param name="rss_FeedLimit">5</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_ExpandFeed">false</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_LCID">1033</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_WebPartID">RSS_Viewer_WebPart</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_alignValue">left</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="rss_IsDesignMode">True</xsl:param>

        <xsl:template match="rss">
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="rdf:RDF">
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="atom:feed">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="atom2:feed">
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="channel/item"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >            
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                        <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(channel/link))}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/>
                        </a>
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                    <div class="item link-item" >
                            <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RSSMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </div>                            
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RSSMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="$rss_alignValue" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- some RSS2.0 contain pubDate tag, some others dc:date -->
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(pubDate) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="pubDateLength" select="string-length(pubDate) - 3" />
                <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(substring(pubDate,0,$pubDateLength),number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(dc:date,number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

                <xsl:if test="string-length(description) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="description"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="no"/> 
                </xsl:if>
             <div class="description"> 
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(link))}">More...</a> 
             </div> 
        </div>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="rss1:item"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:channel/rss1:link))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="rss1:channel/rss1:title"/>
                </a> 
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                    <div class="item link-item" >
                        <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                            <xsl:value-of select="rss1:title"/>   
                        </a>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="RDFMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RDFMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="$rss_alignValue" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(dc:date,number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                <xsl:if test="string-length(rss1:description) &gt; 0">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                        <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="rss1:description"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                     - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                </xsl:if>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(rss1:link))}">More...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom:entry"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
                </a>
            </div>            
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                            <div class="item link-item" >
                                <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
                                </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOMMainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="$rss_alignValue" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
        <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(atom:updated,number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:summary) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:summary"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom:content) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom:content"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <div class="description"> 
                    <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom:link/@href))}">More...</a> 
            </div> 
        </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="atom2:entry"/>
            <xsl:variable name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            <div class="slm-layout-main" >
            <div class="groupheader item medium">                
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body">
                <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="RowCount" select="count($Rows)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.body" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
            <xsl:param name="RowCount"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
                <xsl:variable name="CurPosition" select="position()" />
                <xsl:variable name="RssFeedLink" select="$rss_WebPartID" />
                <xsl:variable name="CurrentElement" select="concat($RssFeedLink,$CurPosition)" />
                <xsl:if test="($CurPosition &lt;= $rss_FeedLimit)">
                     <div class="item link-item" >
                                <a href="{concat(&quot;javascript:ToggleItemDescription('&quot;,$CurrentElement,&quot;')&quot;)}" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="atom2:title"/>
                                </a>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = true()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:block;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$rss_ExpandFeed = false()">
                                <xsl:call-template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="DescriptionStyle" select="string('display:none;')"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="CurrentElement" select="$CurrentElement"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                    </div>
        </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ATOM2MainTemplate.description" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
            <xsl:param name="DescriptionStyle"/>
            <xsl:param name="CurrentElement"/>
        <div id="{$CurrentElement}" class="description" align="$rss_alignValue" style="{$DescriptionStyle} text-align:{$rss_alignValue};">
            <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(atom2:updated,number($rss_LCID),3)"/>
                 <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:summary) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:summary"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length(atom2:content) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:variable name="SafeHtml">
                            <xsl:call-template name="GetSafeHtml">
                                <xsl:with-param name="Html" select="atom2:content"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                         - <xsl:value-of select="$SafeHtml" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            <div class="description">
                <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(atom2:link/@href))}">More...</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:param name="Html"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From the above XSLT I was able to figure out that HTML is generated automatically, that is done by

```
        <xsl:template name="GetSafeHtml">
            <xsl:param name="Html"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$rss_IsDesignMode = 'True'">
                     <xsl:value-of select="$Html"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                     <xsl:value-of select="rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:template>
```

If I am going in the right direction, if HTML is generated automatically, I will not be able to hide those unnecessary links using XSL. So I tried to do that using JQuery.

HTML that is generated automatically is as follows.

```
<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 width=150><tr><td bgcolor="#000000"> <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%" class="pq_all"> <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><td width="100%" align=CENTER colspan=3 nowrap> </td></tr> <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><td width="100%" nowrap>&nbsp;Last </td> <td width="40%" nowrap align=right>45.74</td></tr> <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><td width="100%" nowrap>&nbsp;Change </td> <td width="40%" nowrap align=right><font color="#409940">+1.18</font>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><td width="100%" nowrap>&nbsp;% Change </td> <td width="40%" nowrap align=right><font color="#409940">2.65%</font>&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD"><td width="100%" nowrap>&nbsp;Volume </td> <td width="40%" nowrap align=right>77445704&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><td width="100%" nowrap>&nbsp;Last </td> <td width="40%" nowrap align=right>4:02pm&nbsp;</td></tr> </table> </td></tr></table> _<div><a href="http://cheatcodes.com/iphone/">iPhone Cheat Codes</a></div>_
```

I want to hide the link containing reference to the `http:.//cheatcodes.com/iphone/` which is rendered as "iPhone Cheat Codes" in ITALIC. 
By using JQuery I tried

```
$('a[href*=http://cheatcodes.com]').hide()
```

...... but this doesnt work. I also tried to dig into it and when I tried to fetch the value of href tag using

```
alert($('a[href*=http://cheatcodes.com]')).attr(href)
```

JQuery shows me undefined as a result. Also the links for the cheat codes also get updated on daily basis ... only thing that I found is this portion of the URL remains same is: http:.//cheatcodes.com/... As per my understanding as the HTML is generated automatically JQuery is not able to hide that Anchor tag.

I am kind of stucked into this. If some one gives me light on the exact cause of the behaviour and the solution, I really would appreciate it. Also if some one knows about other RSS feed where I can get the stock quote for the JPMorgan Chase would be helpfull to overcome this issue.

Thanks,
Dhaval

Comment: Please try harder when formatting your code. Your post was unreadable before my edit. (And it's still not great.)

Comment: The first rule is never to use XSLT code that you don't understand. Also, this is *not* an XSLT question at all, because what the `rssaggwrt:MakeSafe($Html)` function returns is a string -- not a (well-formed) XML fragment. In this case XSLT must be used like an ordinary text editor, not like a tree processor. One way to proceed is not to call that extension function at all and to write your own, XSLT code that produces safe XHTML and that filters the unwanted links.

Comment: Do you want an answer? Really?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `alert($('a[href*="http://cheatcodes.com"]')).attr(href)`?